# Why does my bitwise operation return 0 in my emulator?

Tags: javascript, hex, bit-manipulation, emulation, bitwise-operators

So I have this code for my emulator that converts byte to hex

```
byteToHex(opcode) {
        var tempCode = (opcode).toString(16).toUpperCase()
        var addln = 4 - tempCode.length
        var pad =""
        for(var i = 0; i< addln; i++) {
            pad = pad + "0"
        }
        var newCode = "0x"+ pad + tempCode
        return newCode;
}
```

And i have this code that does a bitwise op to get an opcode then converts it for use.

```
this.opcode = (this.memory[this.pc] << 8) | this.memory[this.pc + 1]
    console.log(this.memory)
    console.log("before conversion", this.opcode)
    this.opcode = this.byteToHex(this.opcode)
    console.log(this.opcode)
    //this just returns the first 'letter' of the opcode
    switch (this.opcode & 0xF000)...
```

This is the console output

```
Array [ 240, 144, 144, 144, 240, 32, 96, 32, 32, 112, 70 more… ] 
before conversion 0
0x0000
```

This means I'm getting the opcode incorrectly but I don't know how to fix it.
For a better perspective on the project: [Github](https://github.com/Blaze349/portray)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code that functions as expected. It's a little hard to debug your (incomplete) code. Since StackOverflow is about concrete questions and answers, I'm not even going to bother playing the guessing/detective game needed to work out just where you're going wrong..

240d = 0xF0

144d = 0x90

[240, 144] treated as a single 16 bit big-endian number is 0xF090 (Intel stuff is little-endian, i.e least significant byte comes first)

```js
window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

var memoryContents = [240, 144, 144, 144, 240, 32, 96, 32, 32, 112];

function getTwoLocationsBigEndian(indexOfFirst)
{
 var result = (memoryContents[indexOfFirst] << 8) | (memoryContents[indexOfFirst+1]);
 return result;
}

function getTwoLocationsLittleEndian(indexOfFirst)
{
 var result = (memoryContents[indexOfFirst+1] << 8) | (memoryContents[indexOfFirst]);
 return result;
}

function byteToHex(opcode)
{
 var tempCode = (opcode).toString(16).toUpperCase()
 var addln = 4 - tempCode.length
 var pad =""
 for(var i = 0; i< addln; i++)
 {
  pad = pad + "0"
 }
 var newCode = "0x"+ pad + tempCode
 return newCode;
}

function onDocLoaded(evt)
{
 console.log("Memory contents: " + memoryContents);
 
 var opcode = getTwoLocationsBigEndian(0);
 console.log("***** BIG endian *****");
 console.log("First 2 locs as a 16bit num (dec): " + opcode );
 console.log("First 2 locs as a 16bit num (hex): " + byteToHex(opcode) );

 opcode = getTwoLocationsLittleEndian(0);
 console.log("***** LITTLE endian *****");
 console.log("First 2 locs as a 16bit num (dec): " + opcode );
 console.log("First 2 locs as a 16bit num (hex): " + byteToHex(opcode) );
}
```

Comment: Your code works...when I run it on stackoverflow. It doesn't work for me though...

Comment: Great, that's a good first step. Now it seems, you've to expand "doesn't work for me" into something useful and able to be addressed. What errors do you get in the console, what do you expect as a result, what do you actually get as a result?

Comment: Thank you for responding.  My opcode is set to 0 before being changed to the bitwise result each cycle. It is almost like the function is not giving the opcode any value. There are no js errors though. I still get 0 and 0x0000 as a result.

Comment: also I did link to github as well

Comment: ok I fixed it. It was a problem with the array. Now it is just playing the same value again and again

Comment: Bewdy mate. I hope you'll understand - I'm reluctant/unwilling to visit off-site resources at the best of times. I'm going to refrain in this instance too, unless the task of advancing the PC (program counter) can be shown to be far too complex to be shown in a small snippet. Often, the task of making the question condensed enough and digestible in a format suitable for StackOverflow is one that allows people to solve their own question without posting it. I've written 10+ questions and solved all but one of them during this process itself, hence I've posted just one in nearly 5 yrs.. ;)

Comment: @Blaze349 - no apology necessary my friend. I'm glad to have been able to help you solve the problem.